# Extensions of classifying spaces and higher-groups

Tags: group-theory, higher-category-theory, classifying-spaces, 2-groups

$\newcommand{\B}{\mathrm{B}}\newcommand{\U}{\mathrm{U}}$The extension of a group $G$ by $\B\U(1)$, where $\B$ denotes the classifying space specifies a 2-group, $\tilde{G}_2$
$$ 1\to\B \U(1)\to \tilde{G}_2\to G \to 1. $$
Similarly, extending by $\B^n\U(1)\cong K(\U(1),n)$, where $K(H,m)$ is an Eilenberg-MacLane space, specifies an $n$-group, $\tilde{G}_n$
$$ 1\to\B^n \U(1)\to \tilde{G}_n\to G \to 1. $$

Now, assuming $G$ is abelian (thanks to Qiaochu's comment), What kind of space would $\tilde{G}_?$ be, where
$$ 1\to \B^n\U(1)\to\tilde{G}_?\to \B^m G\to 1\ ?$$
More specifically, taking $G=\U(1)\times\U(1)$, what is
$$1\to \B^n\U(1)\to\tilde{G}_?\to \B^m (\U(1)\times\U(1))\to 1\ ?$$

Comment: If $G$ isn't abelian then $B^m G$ doesn't make sense for $m \ge 2$. If $G$ is abelian then it's some kind of $\text{max}(n, m)$-group again.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Of course, thanks. I guess you meant $(\mathrm{max}(n,m)+1)$-group, though, right? Also, do you have an insight to my addition in v2 (now v3)?